# SQLConnection can not be found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am a web design that is working in MSSQL Server and ASP.Net for the first time in my life. I am trying to connect a database to a form using MVC. My work was really finished when I understand that I must change the connection from the default Visual Studio to code. (Boss told me to!)

I just search to find out how to that and I discover ADO.NET.  So I am trying to change my code but it isn't recognise SQLConnection (red squiggly line saying it can't be found) but I really dont know why. I already searched but nothing helped me. Can you help me pretty please?

Thanks so much!

**Previous code:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    using MVCEmail.Models;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using DQA_DBTemplate.Model;
    using DQA_DBTemplate.DAL.Repositories;
    using DQA_DBTemplate.DAL.Data;

    (...)
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ViewResult Contacts(EmailFormModel _objModelMail){
       if (ModelState.IsValid){
           Email e = new Email();
           e.Address = _objModelMail.FromEmail;
           e.Message = _objModelMail.Message;
           e.Subject = _objModelMail.FromSubject;
           e.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

           try {
              MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
              mail.To.Add(_objModelMail.FromEmail);
              mail.From = new MailAddress("teste_mvc@dqadesign.com");
              mail.Subject = _objModelMail.FromSubject;
              string Body = _objModelMail.Message;
              mail.Body = Body;

              SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
              smtp.Host = "mail.dqadesign.com";
              smtp.Port = 587;
              smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
              smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
              ("teste_mvc@dqadesign.com", "myPassword");
              smtp.Send(mail);
              e.Sent = true;
              email.Insert(e);
              email.Commit();
              return View("Index");
          }
          catch (Exception ex){
              e.Sent = false;
              email.Insert(e);
              email.Commit();
               return View("News");
          }
      }
      return View();
   }

  (...)
```

**Actual Code (of course not complete):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using MVCEmail.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DQA_DBTemplate.Model;
using DQA_DBTemplate.DAL.Repositories;
using DQA_DBTemplate.DAL.Data;

using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
(...)
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ViewResult Contacts(EmailFormModel _objModelMail){
    if(ModelState.IsValid){
       using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("DefaultConnection")){
          var query = "INSERT INTO Emails (@Address,@Subject,@Message,@Date,@Sent)";
          using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query,sqlConnection)){
                 sqlConnection.Open();

                 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", _objModelMail.FromEmail);
                 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", _objModelMail.FromSubject);
                 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", _objModelMail.Message);
                 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                 sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 sqlConnection.Close();
          }
      }
  }
  }
  (...)
```

Comment: please add using System.Data.SqlClient in your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class lives inside `System.Data.SqlClient`. Either add a `using` statement:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Or use the full namespace:

```
var sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("DefaultConnection");
```

Also as a comment on your code, it's a good idea to not use `Parameters.AddWithValue` for [various reasons](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score -1):

```
using(var conn=new. SqlConnection( "server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True"))
{
  conn.Open();
}
```

or

```
string connectionString = "server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True"
using(var conn=new. SqlConnection(connectionString )
{
  conn.Open();
}
```

change the above mentioned connection string with yours and You will have to import

> using System.Configuration;